# railsの起動オプションについて(localhostにアクセスできない)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

はじめまして

最近、会社でRailsの案件を受け持ったのですが、
自宅でRailsを起動するときにはbundle exec rails sとコマンド入力してサーバを立ち上げると
"localhost:3000"でアプリケーションにアクセスできます。

ただ、会社ではbundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0とコマンド入力してサーバを立ち上げて、
"[http://(自分のIPアドレス):3000/](http://(%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AEIP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9):3000/)" にアクセスして開発を行っています。

というのも、会社ではlocalhost:3000にはアクセスができずにLAN内に公開している状態なのですが、どうしてlocalhostにアクセスできないのでしょうか？

考えられる原因などありましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: /etc/hosts でlocalhostの設定を追加・変更していたりはしないでしょうか？

Comment: 今確認したのですがそもそもプロジェクト直下にetcといったフォルダが存在しませんでした...